# Custom Widget stylesheet is not set with property

Tags: qt

I have a custom widget using in my project and I am trying to change background color and label color with the click event. background color changes but label color does not change... Hope someone can help to figure out where I am wrong...

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include "myframe.h"

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

    MyFrame *frame = new MyFrame(this);
    ui->gridLayout_2->addWidget(frame);
    setStyleSheet("MyFrame {background-color: yellow;}"
              "MyFrame QLabel{color: black; font: bold 12px;}"
            "MyFrame[pressed=\"true\"] {background-color:red;}"
            "MyFrame[pressed=\"true\"] QLabel {color:white;}"
                );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

My custom widget //header file

```
#ifndef MYFRAME_H
#define MYFRAME_H

#include <QFrame>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QLabel>
#include <QDebug>

class MyFrame : public QFrame
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(bool pressed READ pressed WRITE setPressed)

    QGridLayout *layout;
    QLabel      *name;

public:
    explicit MyFrame(QWidget *parent = 0);

signals:

public slots:
    bool pressed();
    void setPressed(bool);

protected:
    bool mPressed;
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);

};

#endif // MYFRAME_H
```

//source file

```
#include "myframe.h"

MyFrame::MyFrame(QWidget *parent) :
    QFrame(parent)
{
    mPressed = false;
    layout = new QGridLayout(this);
    setLayout(layout);
    name = new QLabel("button");
    layout->addWidget(name);
}

bool MyFrame::pressed()
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << mPressed;
    return mPressed;
}

void MyFrame::setPressed(bool status)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << status;
    mPressed = status;
}

void MyFrame::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "mouse pressed";
    setPressed(true);
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);
}

void MyFrame::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << Q_FUNC_INFO << "mouse released";
    setPressed(false);
    style()->unpolish(this);
    style()->polish(this);
}
```

The frame background color changes but label color doesn't change on click

Comment: I have edited as style()->unpolish(this);    style()->polish(this);  resolved the issue that qframe background color dint change.

Comment: If you will use customized `QToolButton` instead of `QFrame` you will have same effect without polish/unpolish magic. It is possible to do your task with QSS only.

Comment: This is just a sample application. Actually I need a custom button which is having an image and 3 labels.. so I use like this

Comment: You can have a toolbutton with image and 3 other toolbuttons on it ;). But anyway, it's too ugly. Probably, you will take a look at `QStylePainter` and implement your own `paintEvent` with custom palette?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this properties is not dynamical. It means that stylesheet should not change color when you click button. One way to solve this is to set new stylesheet every clicking. In this case every clicking new stylesheet will be parsed and will be applied with correct colors.

Use one color for `true` and another color for `false`.

```
"MyFrame[pressed=\"true\"] {background-color:red;}"
"MyFrame[pressed=\"false\"] {background-color:yellow;}"
```

Currently I can't find something in documentation to prove my words, but if I'm wrong in something, please point me in comment.

https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-21762

If stylesheet contains large information, then you can polish widget again(call polish)

Comment: You are right, but there are no official documentation. There was a feature request in Qt bugtracker, but it was rejected because of performance reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks .. Resolved the issue..

I have made a trial n error ;)

```
style()->unpolish(this);
style()->unpolish(name);
style()->polish(this);
style()->polish(name);
```

doing this ie, unpolish and polish child also worked